# Getting Nav through ViewChild in Ionic 2 Beta

Tags: angular, routes, ionic2

They just updated Ionic 2 to use Angular 2 RC1, which is great except the routing is still a little strange to me. I was trying to follow along with the update guide, but my nav is still undefined here. The old getComponent method worked, but they got rid of that with this update. It works within a component or a page, but not within a service.

Error I'm getting is `No provider for NavController!`

```
import {IonicApp, NavController, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Injectable, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';

@Injectable()
export class User {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  username: string = 'jaruesink';
  constructor (public nav: NavController) {
  }
  login(username) {
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.username = username;
    this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }
  logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`getActiveNav()`](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/ionic-2-ui-alert-from-a-angular-2-service-221a2e526760).

```
import {App} from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor(private app: App) {}
...
let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
nav.push(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Please remove this answer as it is not possible any more starting from beta 7.

Comment: @user1928596 wrong, it is still there: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/src/components/app/app.ts#L93

Comment: there is no such thing as IonicApp any more, you should correct to App, and your answer helped me yesterday, so up you go when it is fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

If this component is the root component, meaning that it is the initial component that the rest of the app goes into, then the `<ion-nav>` would be `ViewChild` of the root component's template. You would use it the same way you have it above.

However, all other components after the root component is loaded within the `<ion-nav>`, which has a `NavController` that can be injected into any component that was loaded in the root `<ion-nav>`. So your header in this case is probably being loaded "within" an `<ion-nav>`, therefore it's able to inject its parent `NavController`.

Without knowing exactly how your app and templates are setup, my guess is you should try injecting the `NavController` like this:

```
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../../services/user';
import {HeaderServices} from '../../services/header';
import {LoginPage} from '../../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/components/header/header.html',
  selector: 'app-header'
})
export class AppHeader {

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public user: User, private header: HeaderServices) {
  }
  showLogin() {
    this.nav.push(LoginPage);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked. For some reason when I tried NavController before it had some providers error. But now I'm good to go. Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry, I got prematurely excited haha. This works for components but not in my service. I have updated the question to reflect that. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @adam I'm having the same problem. Cannot get a Nav reference in my services and I've tried both the ViewChild and NavController methods.

Comment: We solved this by routing EVERYTHING over app.ts. It would be nice if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic Beta 11 using typescript, it could also go like this:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap, MenuController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {AboutPage} from './pages/about/about';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  providers: [NavController],
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('nav') nav : NavController;
  private pages: any[];
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    this.menu = menu;

    this.pages = [
        { title: 'About', component: AboutPage }
    ];

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.menu.close()
    this.nav.push(page.component);
  };
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

---

Just do this:

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@App({
  templateUrl: '....',
  providers: [....],
  // this is the point
  queries: {
    nav: new ViewChild('content')
  }
})
```

Then go ahead to use as you would previously:

```
this.nav.setRoot(MyPage);
```

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/app/app.js#L24-L26

Comment: They have that for when you're in the App component, but what about within a service?

Comment: @jaruesink Okay, haven't tried that. But *why* would you want a nav controller in your service? Listen to the name, Nav*Controller*. It is like trying to access $scope in your service, angular 1 would scream at you. So, why do you want a nav controller in your service?

Comment: I get what you're saying, but it's another layer of abstraction that seems like it should work.

Comment: @Rexford for example, I have a service that handles authentication, login/logout etc. I want to redirect the user to another page when the user logs in.

Comment: @NunoArruda when the user logs in, instead of redirecting in the service you're supposed to do so in your controller. Why are you trying to do the job of a controller in a service.? It is called a service or provider for a very good reason. Technically, you're asking to do routing in a service, which is weird.

Comment: @Rexford I am using a service so I can inject it in whatever  page I need. Otherwise I would have to repeat code in every page controller I need to handle authentication, and that's weird.

Comment: Can confirm this works in Beta 11. Until I can use RC5 or the final release this works perfectly.